# More efficient solution than many loop iterations with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have written an algorithm that returns the smallest common multiple of two integers that can be evenly divided by both, and can also be evenly divided by all sequential integers in the range between the initial two integers.

My algorithm works well for numbers where the smallest common multiple is a reasonably low number. For numbers where the smallest common multiple is a very large number (ex for [1,13] its 360360) my algorithm breaks because it is dependant on running more and more for loops.

I have posted my code below. It seems very long, but the problem section is near the beginning, and the rest of the code is added for context.

Is there a more efficient solution that running more and more loop iterations to return larger numbers?

```
// If mystery failure occurs, examine i & j loop limits.
function smallestCommons(arr) {
var firstArray = [];
var secondArray = [];
var commonNums = [];
var sequential = [];

// Sort the array from lowest to highest
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a-b;
});

// Assing arr values to vars so that original data stays intact
var array0 = arr[0];
var array1 = arr[1];
//console.log(arr);
// Find all multiples of both inputs.

// THIS IS THE PROBLEM SECTION
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
firstArray.push(arr[0] * (i+1));
}
for (var j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
secondArray.push(arr[1] * (j+1));
}
// THAT WAS THE PROBLEM SECTION

// Find common multiples.
for (var k = 0; k < firstArray.length; k++) {
  for (var l = 0; l < secondArray.length; l++) {
if (firstArray[k] == secondArray[l]) {
  commonNums.push(firstArray[k]);
} // End if.
} // End l loop.
} // End k loop.

// Find sequential numbers in range between input parameters.
for (var m = 0; m < array1; m++) {
if (array0 + 1 !== array1) {
  sequential.push(array0 += 1);
} // End of if.
} // End of m loop.

// Find commonNums divisible by arr && sequential to produce a whole number.
// commonNums [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75]
// arr [1,5]
// sequential [ 2, 3, 4 ]
for (var n = 0; n < commonNums.length; n++) {
    var match = true;
    for (var o = 0; o < sequential.length; o++) {
        for (var p = 0; p < arr.length; p++) {
            if (commonNums[n] % arr[p] !== 0 || commonNums[n] % sequential[o] !== 0) {
                match = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(match) {
console.log(commonNums[n]);
    }

} // End of n loop.

} // End function.

smallestCommons([1,13]);
```

Comment: es6 should have Set, could remove looping secondArray

Answer (score 1):

What you do does not make a lot of sense and is really hard to read. All you need to know to solve this problem is a little bit of math. And this math tells you that:

```
lcm(a, b) = a * b / gcd(a, b)
lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(a,lcm(b,c))
```

which translates into something like this:

```
function gcd(a, b){
  while (b !== 0) {
    var tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp % b;
  }
  return a
}

function lcm(a, b){
  return a * b / gcd(a, b);
}

function lcm_arr(arr){
  var res = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     res = lcm(res, arr[i]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

which gives you your results in less than a second:
`lcm_arr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])`

Comment: With longer ranges in languages with infinite integers, you would want to do `lcm(lcm(first half), lcm(second half))`.  That will perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good place to use [recursion](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-lesson-205/0/1), because you have a solid base case when the number difference is one (in your example `smallestCommons([12,13]);` or `smallestCommons([1,2]);` depending on the direction), and the rest (sequentials) would be incrementing the smaller or decrementing the bigger number in recursive calls. That could save you quite a few CPU cycles.

Comment: Also, maybe you could consider moving this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because it doesn't have an error or a problem per se, but needs optimization.